# /var/log/rgc main.log very large file preventing server operation

Tags: linux, ubuntu

The root partition on our Ubuntu server has just filled and the web portal no longer works.

I tried locating the large file and discovered:

```
/var/log$ du -h --max-depth=1
3.6M    ./apache2
12K     ./fsck
1.2M    ./mysql
4.0K    ./news
51G     ./rgc
etc.
```

On closer inspection, I see:

```
/var/log/rgc$ ls -l
total 52601768
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 53811597822 2016-01-07 10:01 main.log
```

Does anyone know any reason why main.log could grown so big and why it is being written to the folder rgc?

As advised by ljazKhan, I tried lsof

```
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ ls -l
total 75884
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 77620032 2016-01-07 11:46 main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ lsof | grep main.log
ubuntu@x:/var/log/rgc$ ls -l
total 76360
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root 78107085 2016-01-07 11:47 main.log
```

As you can see the file was updated but I never saw it as open.

I don't understand why lsof reveals nothing but it is an exception error being logged.

I'm going to follow ljazKhan advice until the issue can be root caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you dont have any log rotation for this file. you should clear this file depending on your requirement , may be daily , weekly , monthly.

```
 cat /dev/null > /var/log/.rgc/main.log
```

Also ,

do an `lsof | grep main.log` to see which process is producing it.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, any ideas what rgc is linked to?  Just ten minutes after deletion it is already 11M.  Trying to figure out why so much data is being written to this folder.

Comment: For time being you can write a srcipt that keep monitoring this file and clear it if the size grows than some limit.

Comment: @SeanJ: Maybe the contents of the log file will give you a clue, as will `fuser /var/log/rgc/main.log`, which should show the process writing to it.

Comment: Have you installed some gaming thing on your machine? its some gaming package

Comment: @ljazKhan I certainly didn't install a gaming package.  Could it be that our system has been hacked?  I'm not even sure how that could happen in AWS

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz Running `fuser /var/log/rgc/main.log` does not yield a response.  Up to 26M now, very strange...

Comment: Ok , list the you process by using top or ps , and see what unusual process is running by grepping rgc , also check installed packages and locate rgc

Comment: @IjazKhan `dpkg --get-selections | grep rgc` shows nothing and also `ps aux | grep rgc` reveals nothing except for the grep

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: @IjazKhan tried `lsof | grep main.log` but no response back.  Curiouser and curiouser.

Comment: lsof must have some response , it lists all the open files and it must list the main.log , you should wait for its output

Comment: @IjazKhan Please see update to question. I'm baffled.